# Change update authority for Solana token

Tags: solana, cryptocurrency

Creating a new Solana token and using the Solana CLI and file system wallet  https://solscan.io/token/VRDcnUZB48GAPQm13DtxbGLwwAZPJWm6FbpiAGkkJhk#metadata

I overwrote my config json file `--config ~/.config/solana/id.json` and am looking to try to update this new tokens update authority (if that is possible).

I have tried changing the mint address with

`spl-token authorize VRDcnUZB48GAPQm13DtxbGLwwAZPJWm6FbpiAGkkJhk mint AxzXAmVr2EWfBr7rsakwUkFknNSFg431g7AXe23YGAes --program-id {programId}`

and I get back

```
  Current mint authority: AxzVRbyT8HgM1QRZX9SVA2YYxvkRZEMFucbxrpZDqX5P
  New mint authority: AxzXAmVr2EWfBr7rsakwUkFknNSFg431g7AXe23YGAes
  Error: The account did not have the expected program id
```

Hopefully can figure a way to recover this token

Answer (score 0):

Did you kept your secret phrase when you created your wallet with the CLI ? If yes you should be able to recover your wallet through know solana wallet provider and export the private key back from them. Then you would have to create a new id.json and paste the private key. (Array format)